# Can't add prisma to Existing database

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

I am connecting my existing database to Prisma. I am followed the documentation (https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/add-to-existing-project/relational-databases/baseline-your-database-typescript-sqlserver). But the baseline step is throwing an error that is given below,
the command I tried is "npx prisma migrate resolve --applied 0_init". Anybody have the same issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with VS Code only. When I tried the same command in CMD it works